# Getting Syntax error while reading last 2 hrs logs using Awk command

Tags: shell, awk

I am new to shell script and trying to read the last 2 hrs logs from the file but getting some syntax.could someone please help me out..

My log file contents are:

### test.log

```
AppDebug,2011-12-18 12:08:45:990,ret521v,TEST,TEST Hub,,,,,,,2,49601060
AppDebug,2011-12-18 12:09:34:891,ret521v,TEST,TEST Hub,,,,,,,4,49588825
AppDebug,2011-12-18 12:10:08:485,ret521v,TEST,TEST Hub,,,,,,,4,49588826
AppDebug,2011-12-18 12:11:21:603,ret521v,TEST,TEST Hub,,,,,,,4,49588827
AppDebug,2011-12-18 12:12:05:430,ret521v,TEST,TEST Hub,,,,,,,4,49588828
AppDebug,2011-12-18 12:12:08:376,ret521v,TEST,TEST Hub,,,,,,,38,ResponseTrackId49588828
```

### My Script

```
#!/bin/sh
awk -vDate=`date -d'now-2 hours' +%Y-%m-%d" "%H:%M:%S` '{ if ($2 > Date) print ;}' test.log
```

### Output

```
awk: 11:50:00
awk:   ^ syntax error
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 awk -F"," -vDate="`date -d'now-2 hours' +%Y-%m-%d" "%H:%M:%S`" '{ if ($2 > Date) print ;}'
```

Two things: specify coma as the fields separator and put quotes around the value for the "Date" variable.